# How can I add a print statement to this code without getting an indentation error

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to learn an unfamilar code base. I want to add a print statement just below the def line.  But every time I do so for one of these very short methods I get an indentation error.

```
def rename(self, old, new):
    #print 'this will bring an error if left uncommented'       
    return os.rename(self._full_path(old), self._full_path(new))
```

How can I add a print statement to a short method like this?

Comment: This "should be" no problem at all. Make sure you're not mixing spaces with tabs! If it's code you didn't write, the author may have had a different idea than your editor does about what a tab means. I prefer all spaces.

Comment: @TimPeters how many spaces equals a tab?

Comment: That's the point: there is no defined answer to that. Unix programmers usually think "8", Windows programmers often think "4". That's why tabs suck in contexts where whitespace is significant. **Try something.** All I can tell from here is that the sample you posted used all spaces for indentation. That's fine. There's no SyntaxError when I try it.

Comment: @akh2103 Which editor are you using?

Comment: And which version of Python are using?  If you're using Python 3, `print` is *not* a statement there - in Python 3 you need to use `print` as a function instead.

Comment: Full error message / stack trace please... To avoid guesses about tabs, spaces, python versions or your grandmother's shoe size.

Comment: See question and answer to [_elif giving syntax error python?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745740/elif-giving-syntax-error-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A tab is a tab *character* (just like `\n` is a newline character), you can configure most editors to replace a tab character with a certain number of spaces.

The [convention in Python is to indent by four spaces](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) and to use spaces instead of tabs.  This is the recommendation; but people tend to do what they please.

It is most likely that the code is indented by tabs and you are using spaces. @TimPeters wrote [reindent.py](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Tools/scripts/reindent.py) that will take a Python file and convert tabs into spaces.

There are other tools as well. Most editors have a function that can do this, if the editor is Python aware they may have a specific function for just this. For example [pycharm](/questions/tagged/pycharm) has a "Convert Indents" menu option under Edit.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
def rename(self, old, new):
    print('this will bring an error if left uncommented')       
    return os.rename(self._full_path(old), self._full_path(new))
```

Whenever I have trouble with the print keyword, I can usually solve it by using print() instead.

Comment: Treating `print` as a keyword when it's a function would throw a `SyntaxError`, not an `IndentationError`.

Comment: @Blender, I'm sorry, but it was at least a suggestion that should work.

Comment: It won't really change anything if OP has an indentation problem.